# finding the maximum in a HashSet<u32> in rust?

Tags: rust

how can i find the maximum or minimum value in a HashSet without looping through all the elements in it? Is there any function or one liner way to do so ?

Comment: What have you tried? `HashSet` has the [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html#method.iter) method, which returns [an iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_set/struct.Iter.html) with some useful methods on it...

Comment: How do you expect this to work? `HashSet` doesn't store anything other then the values and their hashes, so the only way to find the maximum is to compare all the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
let hs: HashSet<u32> = HashSet::from_iter(vec![54, 23, 55, 6, 3, 100]);
let min_value = *hs.iter().min().unwrap();
let max_value = *hs.iter().max().unwrap();
```

That way *you* won't have to loop yourself, but internally that's exactly what is going to happen. It's not possible to find the min or max value in a hash set (or a hash map, for that matter), without checking *all* the values.

BTW there is another (relatively common) set type, [BTreeSet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html), which keeps its values ordered. That would allow you to simply get the first or the last element (via `iter().next()` or `iter().next_back()`) and you've got you min/max value w/o any extra work. Performance-wise that would be much faster of course.